# The bundle 'XXXXXXX' cannot be deleted. Delete all the Apps related to this bundle to proceed

Tags: ios, bundle-identifier

I tried to delete unused app ID on Apple Developer Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles, but then the below dialog popped up. I don't have any associated app with this bundle ID. Why can't I delete the bundle ID?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There was an associated service ID. I was able to delete the bundle ID after deleting the service ID.

Comment: This also solved it for me, don't know why Apple tells one to "delete all the Apps" which is plain bs. Anyways, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for deleting a bundle. I found the associated services after quite some time, as the interface to access Services IDs is not very intuitive.

Here is a screenshot to help others. Just click on **App IDs** on the right side and then on **Service IDs** in the drop-down menu.

[image]